# How to append data in html using conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery

Developers I know this is duplicate question to other, but I want understand more details to my problem,

**Question:How to append data in html in conditional way?**

Scenario: If the `condition_direction` value is `Right` fetch all the data in the direction of right, else go to the `Left`.

**I have here my function:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost:8000/api/story',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success:function(response) {
            console.log(response);

            var historytable = response[0].historytable;
            $.each(historytable, function (index, el) {

            var stringify_historytable = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(el));
            var condition_direction = stringify_historytable['content_section'];
            var condition_content_title = stringify_historytable['content_title'];

            console.log(condition_direction);

            var data;

            data += "<li>" if(condition_direction == 'Right') {
                'Go to Right'
            }else{
                'Go to Left'
            }

            "</li>";




            $('#time_line_data').html(data);

          });
        },
        error:function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

**My Html:**

```
<ul class="timeline" id="time_line_data">

</ul>
```

**I already solved this problem to my laravel project
i used this code to solve that.**

Question: how to translate this code to jquery language?

```
@foreach($historytable as $history_content)
    <li>
        @if($history_content->content_section == 'Right')
            <div class="direction-r">
                <div class="flag-wrapper">
                    <span class="hexa"></span>

                    <span class="time-wrapper"><span class="time">{{$history_content->content_title}}</span></span>
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    {!! $history_content->content !!}
                </div>
            </div>


        @else
            <div class="direction-l">
                <div class="flag-wrapper">
                    <span class="hexa"></span>

                    <span class="time-wrapper"><span class="time">{{$history_content->content_title}}</span></span>
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    {!! $history_content->content !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif  
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: data += "<li>" + (condition_direction == 'Right') ? 'Go to Right' : 'Go to Left' + "</li>";

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the way you are using concatenation. It should be:

```
data += "<li>" + ((condition_direction == 'Right') ? 'Go to Right' : 'Go to Left') + "</li>";
```

Use a ternary operator in this case. Simple ternary operators are of the syntax:

```
<condition> ? <expression if true> : <expression if false>
```

**Snippet**

```js
data = "";
condition_direction = "Right";
data += "<li>" + ((condition_direction == 'Right') ? 'Go to Right' : 'Go to Left') + "</li>";
console.log(data);

data = "";
condition_direction = "Left";
data += "<li>" + ((condition_direction == 'Right') ? 'Go to Right' : 'Go to Left') + "</li>";
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Kumar , hi can you see the new update of my question. thanks.

Comment: @DevGe My name's Praveen.

Comment: @DevGe Ask a new question.  Happy to answer that. You may accept this and create a new one.

Comment: Thanks Kumar I will upload new.. thanks for answering my first question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float` right and left.
This may help you

> ```
>       var data;
>       if(condition_direction == 'Right') {
>           data += "<li style='float:right;'>"; 
>       }
>       else {
>           data += "<li style='float:left;'>" >            
>       }
>       data+="your content";
>       data+="</li>";
>
>       $('#time_line_data').html(data);
> ```

OR you can write in one line code

> ```
>       data += "<li style='float:"+ condition_direction.toLowerCase()+"'>";
> ```

Comment: You sure you understood the question?